# Connect to CRM with only webservies

Tags: web-services, dynamics-crm, sqlclr

Can someone please point me to the direction where there is a example on how to connect and retrieve data from Microsoft Dynamic online 2011 with only the web services, such as  Discovery and Organization, and not using any of the SDK that Microsoft provided.  It would also be nice if I dont need to add System.ServiceModel. 
I looked at the [Soap example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CRM-Online-2011-WebServices-14913a16) it still used Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Samples.

The reason i am avoiding any SDK or namespace is I am trying to build a SQL CLR that can connect to CRM online and retrieve the data i needed for the reports.  The reports are based on my local database and CRM data.

Thank you for all the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most data can be fetched (and relationships are well represented) via the oData/REST web services. You don't need any particular SDKs or custom code, just anything that can read data in XML or JSON format from a URI.

`[Your Organization Root URL]/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc` is where you'll find the fun stuff. Documentation is on MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334767.aspx